# Customize I18n for time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I use [time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) for both future timestamps and past.

This is how my `en.yml` looks like:

```
datetime:
  distance_in_words:
    x_days:
      one:   "1 day"
      other: "%{count} days"
```

I want to print out "yesterday" instead of "1 day" if the timestamp isn't future.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO, `time_ago_in_words` simply call `distance_of_time_in_words` setting the `to_time` param to `Time.now`.

Edit: For the sake of readability.

Long answer (discussed in comments): It's possible to use `distance_of_time_in_words` setting the `:scope` option to use your translations rather than the default ones. Still, tomorrow and yesterday are "1 day" from now, so it's necessary to wrap it on a custom method that treats past and future dates differently.

Comment: So I suppose `distance_of_time_in_words` doesn't offer the option to scope an I18n key either?

Comment: It does, but tomorrow and yesterday both use the same key: 1 day away.

Comment: I was thinking if it was possible to set a custom key, I could wrap `distance_of_time_in_words` in a method that checks if future or past and give each their unique keys.

Comment: You just arrived at the long answer, YES. See how they have a scope option on `distance_of_time_in_words`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L71

Comment: That solved it! Thank you. If you want to update your answer, this worked for me: `distance_of_time_in_words(DateTime.current - 26.hours, DateTime.current, scope: :'datetime.custom_key')`

Comment: I did, just one last comment on style: `distance_of_time_in_words(26.hours.ago, Time.current, ...` reads more Ruby-ish.